# Twitter bootstrap sass not working on some pages

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've installed the bootstrap-sass gem and I am finding the css works on some pages and not others, which I am not sure why this is.Below I've included the views in which it's not working, the Gemfile and the stylesheets.

gemfile:-
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.15.1'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", '~> 3.0.1' 
gem "paperclip", '~> 3.4.2'
gem "will_paginate", '~> 3.0.4'
gem "friendly_id", '~> 4.0.9'
gem 'stripe'

group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2'
end

group :test do
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.2'
 gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
 gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1'
 gem 'launchy', '~> 2.3'
 gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 3.0.1'
 gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.1'
 gem 'webmock'
end

group :development do
 gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"
end

group :test, :development do
 gem 'database_cleaner'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.2'
 gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 3.0.1'
 gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
 gem 'fuubar', '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.1'
```

application.css.scss:-

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
 @import "bootstrap";
```

baskets.html.erb

```
<p><%= notice %></p>

<p><%= @basket_items.product_totals %><p>

<%= button_to "Purchase products", new_payment_path, :class => "btn" %>

<table class="table table-hover">
 <tr>
  <th>Picture</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <% @basket_items.each do |item| %>
    <td><p>Nothingness</p></td>
    <td><p><%= item.product.name %></p></td>
    <td><p><%= item.product.price %></p></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'Remove', basket_item_path(item.id), :method => 'delete', :confirm    => 'Are you sure?', :class => "btn" %></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
</table>
```

categories show
show.html.erb

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
<p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>

<div class="search">
 <%= form_tag(search_path, method: "get", :class => "form-search") do %>
 <%= text_field_tag(:query, nil, :class => "input-medium search-query") %>
 <%= submit_tag("Search", :class => "btn") %>
<% end %>
</div>  

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<% @cp.each do |p| %>
  <div class="product"> 
    <div class="product-image">
      <%= image_tag p.image %>
    </div>
    <p><%= p.price %></p>
    <p><%= link_to p.name, product_path(p.slug) %></p>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

categories.css.scss

```
.product {
  display: inline-block;
 }

.product-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
 }

.row-fluid {
margin-top: 300px;
 }

.search {
  margin: 100px 10px 0px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: What specifically is "not working"? You should use developer tools like Google Chrome's to check any error messages and view the source to see if Bootstrap's CSS is there. Have you tried refreshing? In development using the standard rails server, assets will 404 on a page load from time to time.

Comment: The bootstrap components such as buttons,tables etc...I've tried refreshing it a number over times. I've looked at the google chrome inspect element tool and I can see under network tab not all the assests are being loaded such as the application.css which imports the bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could be more specific than "not working", but generally if assets aren't loading correctly or older versions of assets are showing instead, there is good chance you forgot to precompile your assets.

Try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, then reload the page.

Comment: By it's not working I mean when I set for example a button_to to have a class btn or a table from bootstrap they don't use the twitter-bootstrap css on some of the pages, which I am not sure why as other pages have twitter bootstrap working. I have tried bundle exec rake assests:compile and they don't show in my development environment.

Comment: Within the <head> </head> elements I don't see any css loaded at all, what could be the reason? as it works fine on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me it was because I had an assets folder in my vendor directory, and within that a stylesheets folder. I assume that rails checked those folders for bootstrap because they existed instead of importing the bootstrap gem? Once I deleted those it worked perfectly.